# Scroll 2 listview at same time

Tags: java, listview, javafx

In my `JavaFX` project I was using 2 `TextFlows` to display some text. I used `vvalueProperty` of `ScrollPanes` which are holding the `TextFlows` to scroll both `TextFlow` at same time

```
scrolPane1.vvalueProperty().bindBidirectional(scrolPane2.vvalueProperty());
```

But since `TextFlow` is only support in `Java 8`, Im trying to replace them with `ListView`. 
How can I scroll 2 `ListViews` at same time? Since `ListView` contains a inner `ScrollPane` my approach that worked with TextFlow doesn't work here.

Simply I want to scroll 2 `ListViews` at same time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try something like

```
Platform.runLater(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        Node n = listView1.lookup(".scroll-bar");
        if (n instanceof ScrollBar) {
            final ScrollBar bar = (ScrollBar) n;
            if (bar.getOrientation().equals(Orientation.VERTICAL)) {
                // get the second scrollbar of another listview and bind values of them
            }
        }
    }
});
```